# How can I change a scene inside a scene (basically, change an inactive scene)

Tags: godot

I am making an adventure game and, in order to go inside buildings, I would have to change scenes. I wanted to ask, since I want to keep the UI when I am entering buildings, how can I swap out a scene that is not the  current one?

I am now using the `scenemanager` that I got from the official Godot documentation to switch scenes, but it doesn't have any functions to swap existing scenes.

I was thinking about placing a main scene within the UI and then another scene which would hold yet another scene. That last scene would be the one switching.

Comment: You might want to think about creating your UI as it's own scene, and then instancing it in all the other scenes you want to have it in. That way, you can have the same UI in any scene you want, perhaps with values updated through singleton if necessary. This page has a pretty good breakdown of the mechanics of a scene swap - https://godotengine.org/qa/24773/how-to-load-and-change-scenes

Comment: This tutorial might also be helptul: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4_DVbZwmYc